# LibGDX Label centering doesn't work properly after updating text

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a problem. I'm creating a simple menu for my LibGDX game. I create a label as follows:

```
Label label = new Label("Text", new Label.LabelStyle(font, Color.WHITE));
label.setPosition(960, 960, Align.center);
stage.addActor(label);
```

As you can see, I set the position along with the centering. The problem occurs when I want to update the label text with *setText()* method. Centering is completely broken.

```
label.setText("New text");
```

I tried re-executing the *setPosition()* method as in the example above, but it didn't help. I would like to know why after updating the text LibGDX still remembers the old label size. What's a good way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the alignment of a label will **only align the text within the label**, but not the label itself.
From the [libgdx API](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/9fb9353c99ae5b30b455262832c13a84c2736bd4/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.java#L515) (class Actor, which is a super class of Label):

> /** Sets the position of the actor's bottom left corner. */
> public void setPosition (float x, float y)

If you want to center the text within your label you can **set the bounds of the label** (see the [libgdx API](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/9fb9353c99ae5b30b455262832c13a84c2736bd4/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.java#L628) for reference).

This will change the position along with the width and height of the label. Then the text of the label will be centered within this label.

Answer (score 1):

To set the label alignment, you should use the `setAlignment` method:

```
label.setAlignment(Align.center);
```

The `int alignment` argument of the `Actor.setPosition` method specifies how the actor should be aligned in relation to the passed `x` and `y` position. This method only updates the label position, not its alignment.

The `Label.setAlignment` method, on the other hand, updates the `labelAlign` and `lineAlign` properties of the `Label` class, which have a direct effect on the label position and how it is updated within layout invalidation.